# can we use angular in sitefinity project?

Tags: angular, sitefinity-10

I am planning to create a website using sitefinity CMS and am not sure if it is possible to use Angular on the project. Does sitefinity support Angular?

Comment: Sitefinity uses Angular 2 in the backend. For the front-end you can use whatever you like.

Comment: It is possible, but "Sitefinity officially supports Angular 1.4.8 at this time for its Feather MVC widget designers." https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/does-sitefinity-support-angular-2